# How to style an ARIA Role Table with aria-colspan

Tags: css, grid, wai-aria

For a project I am trying too creating an ARIA table that includes aria-colspan="4". I am using CSS Grid to layout the table, but cannot work out how to style when the element spans multiple columns.

I'd appreciate help in how to make the aria-colspan 4 visually span the 4 columns and the role cells to be positioned under this.

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/Deafinitive/pen/eYvmvKq)

HTML

```
<div role="table">
  <div role="rowgroup">
    <div role="row">
      <div role="columnheader">th 1</div>
      <div role="columnheader">th 2</div>
      <div role="columnheader">th 3</div>
      <div role="columnheader">th 4</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div role="rowgroup">
    <div role="row">
      <div role="cell">tb 1</div>
      <div role="cell">tb 2</div>
      <div role="cell">tb 3</div>
      <div role="cell">tb 4</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div role="rowgroup">
    <div role="row">
      <div role="columnheader" aria-colspan="4">Spans 4 columns</div>
    </div>
  </div>
    <div role="rowgroup">
    <div role="row">
      <div role="cell">tb 1a</div>
      <div role="cell">tb 2a</div>
      <div role="cell">tb 3a</div>
      <div role="cell">tb 4a</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
```

CSS

```
:root {
  --table-header: #9900ff;
  --table-row-even: #ccccff;
  --table-cell: #141414;
}

div[role="table"] {
  display: grid;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border:1px solid red;
  min-width: 100%;
  grid-template-columns: 
    minmax(25%, 100%)
    minmax(25%, 100%)
    minmax(25%, 100%)
    minmax(25%, 100%);
}

div[role="rowgroup"],
div[role="row"]{
  display: contents;
}

div[role="columnheader"],
div[role="cell"]{
  padding: 0.25em 1em;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

div[role="columnheader"]{
  background: var(--table-header);
  color:#FFF;
}

div[role="columnheader"][aria-colspan="4"]{
  background: red;
}

div[role="columnheader"]:last-child {
  border: 0;
}

div[role="cell"]{
  padding-top: 1em;
  padding-bottom: 1em;
  color: var(--table-cell);
}

div[role="row"]:nth-child(even) div[role="cell"] {
  background: var(--table-row-even);
}
```

Once again I am stuck! is going to be my epitaph.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to fix this, is to change your layout from grid to flex, but this is not going to work if you want to use a different value in `aria-colspan`:

```
div[role="table"] {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

div[role="rowgroup"],div[role="row"] {
  display: flex;
}
div[role="row"]{
  flex: 1;
}

div[role="columnheader"],
div[role="cell"]{
  padding: 0.25em 1em;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
  flex: 1;
}
```

The alternative is to actually build a HTML table and add the ARIA tags in each table element.

Comment: The main objective for this exercise is to determine if JAWS screen reader announces the role columnheader when it is inserted within the table. So far it seems buggy.